# Delphi 10.2 How do I get Log.d to ignore % in the HTML source code?

Tags: delphi, format, arguments, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

**How do I get `Log.d` to ignore `%` in the HTML source code?  Or tell `Log.d` not to format the code?**

The HTML code I send to my program:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Mode" value="Search%20Statutes" />
```

The procedure I created:

```
procedure ThtmlParser.DebugText(ExtraStr, Str: string);
var
  CombineStrings: string;
begin
  CombineStrings := ExtraStr + Str;
  Log.d(CombineStrings);
  if Assigned(FOnDebug) then
  begin
     FOnDebug(CombineStrings);
  end;
end;
```

How I use it:

```
Target := '<input type="hidden" name="Mode" value="Search%20Statutes" />'
DebugText('Target: ', Target);
```

The error I'm getting:

```
First chance exception at $756C1812. Exception class EConvertError with message 'No argument for format 'Target: <input type="hidden" na''. Process htmlParserExample.exe (5168)
```

What I think is happening, that `Log.d` thinks the `%` in the HTML code is for formating when it is not.

Comment: Where is the rest of ThtmlParser declared?  What is the declaration of log.d?

Comment: @MartynA Log.d is in FMX.Types

Comment: @DaveNottage:  But how are readers supposed to guess that that's what the OP is referring to?  There isn't even a FireMonkey tag on the q.

Comment: @MartynA log.d is accessible to VCL projects as well, despite being in FMX.Types!

Comment: @PatHeuvel:  Yes, but readers shouldn't have to guess whether that is te log.d the OP intended; the information should be in the q.

Comment: @MartynA Fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Delphi is "looking for a format", I gave it a format to follow.

I am not sure why Delphi's developing team would create a `class procedure d(const Msg: string); overload; inline;`  and not let us use it?  That is what got me confused.  So instead, I used this instead:

```
class procedure d(const Fmt: string; const Args: array of const); overload;
```

Here is my new procedure that fixes my issue:

```
procedure ThtmlParser.DebugText(ExtraStr, Str: string);
var
  CombineStrings: string;
begin
  CombineStrings := ExtraStr + Str;
  Log.d('%s',[CombineStrings]);
  if Assigned(FOnDebug) then
  begin
     FOnDebug(CombineStrings);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would use `Log.d('%s%s', [ExtraStr, Str])` instead, and get rid of `CombineStrings`. You should also [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) about the single-argument version of `Log.d()` misbehaving. It should not be formatting anything.

Comment: @Remy, ElDiablo: `Log.d(Msg)` seems to call `Log.d(Msg, []);`. That is a mistake, indeed. It should be the other way around. Or it could call `Log.d('%s', [Msg]);`. That would be fine.

Comment: Was just notified that my report was a duplicate of https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20021 and that this is resolved in Delphi 10.3 Rio.